# script/curl stops after a while

Tags: php, regex, curl

I did a tools for my project that you put a bunch of password and it code it into MD5 this is what i tried

```
<?
foreach($pass as $password){
set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"md5=$password");
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);

$con = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

now when the script works when it arrives to the password number 150 or 200 it stops i don't know what is the problem, for example:

```
1-password is: md5()
2-password is: md5(2)
3-password is: md5(3)
```

after that it stops without any warning what i want is i don't want the script to be stopped until he finish all the passwords and if it stuck or stops i want to display all the passwords that wasn't been encrypted so i reduce time to not repeat all the progress.

Comment: Sidenote : You have a typo here `CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFERE,TRUE);`

Comment: yeah i fixed it now thank you, but it works fine and this is not the problem

Comment: Why not just use the native md5($password) function?

Comment: they asked me to use curl so we learn how to use curl

Comment: Are you flooding the server in question and getting banned? Try throwing a `sleep(1);` after `curl_close`

Comment: no i'm not flooding the server but my question is simple i want the script display for me the codes that he didn't encrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Set_time_limit(0);`

Or you can edit the php.ini file to do it, but this can be done only if you are the server administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You should put time limit for the script

```
Set_time_limit(0);
```

Put it in the top of the code and it will prevent the stopping of the script.